# Wordpress post save/edit post hook

Tags: wordpress, post, hook

I'm looking for a admin hook for posts that gets fired after the post has been saved. The problem: the `save_post` does not contain the already changed data to the post object. The new changes can only be found in the `$_POST` array. But I need a way to update the permalink to a external API once the `post_name` changes. But it will not work since the `$post` object is still the old one before the save action.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to hook in after the post has been updated using the priority argument (set to 20 in this example):

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'your_function', 20, 1 );
function your_function( $post_id ) {
    // this should be the updated post object 
    $post = get_post( $post_id );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the most suitable method is to query the old values from the database and compare the values with `$_POST` array values.

Here is the link which should help you to read values from database.

http://codex.wordpress.org/wpdb#query_-_Run_Any_Query_on_the_Database

P.S: You should of course make this comparison "before" saving the new values to the database.

Answer (score 1):

Since WordPress 3.0.0 the [`post_updated`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_updated/) hook is available. It helps to know what has changed in the post after the update. You can use [the example](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/post_updated#Example) in the WP Codex as a sample.

```
add_action( 'post_updated', 'check_updated_post_name', 10, 3 );
function check_updated_post_name( $post_ID, $post_after, $post_before ) {
    if ( $post_after->post_name != $post_before->post_name ) {
        // do what you need
    }
}
```

And if a post has just been inserted you can use [`save_post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/) or [`save_post_{$post->post_type}`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post_post-post_type/) hooks. Check the value of the third argument to make sure the post is new.

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'check_new_post_name', 10, 3 );
function check_new_post_name( $post_ID, $post, $update ) {
    if ( ! $update ) {
        // do what you need
    }
}
```